# Я чайник и решил написать змейку

Tags: python, python-3.x, функции

```
apple = turtle.Turtle()
apple.shape('circle')
apple.color('red')
apple.penup()
apple.speed(0)


xapple = int
yapple = int


def randomAppleXcor():

    xapple == random.randrange(-600, 600)

def randomAppleYcor():
    yapple == random.randrange(-500,500)


randomAppleXcor()
randomAppleYcor()

apple.goto(xapple, yapple)
```

Это место с рандомным появлением яблока. Оно ещё сырое и по должно появляться только одно яблоко, но даже оно не появляется! Что не так?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Дружище, в строках

```
xapple = int
yapple = int
```

не указываешь, что xapple и yapple это целочисленные значения, а передаёшь в эти названия классы. В питоне не как в сиподобных языках, тут не нужно указывать тип переменной.

А вот оператор `==` это не оператор присваивания, а оператор сравнения. Он будет выводить только True или False, поэтому функции

```
def randomAppleXcor():

    xapple == random.randrange(-600, 600)

def randomAppleYcor():
    yapple == random.randrange(-500,500)
```

будут просто передавать значения False и уходить эти значения будут в никуда. Тебе нужно исправить `==` на `=` и убрать

```
xapple = int
yapple = int
```

Также тебе нужно объявить xapple и yapple любое значение, но, пусть это будет 0 и 0, так как мы используем целочисленное значение. А также в питоне, что было внутри функции, остаётся внутри функции помимо return и global (ну и ещё несколько). Поэтому мы пишем

```
global xapple
```

и

```
global yapple
```

в соответствующих функциях, чтобы питон работал именно с основными переменными, а только внутри функции.

Также я бы заменил в твоём случае на random.randint(), вместо random.randrange(), ибо, думаю, у тебя они будут по клеточкам двигаться. Также, у тебя (-600, 600) и (-500, 500) - большой слишком размах. Экран не такой большой. Я указал (-10, 10) и (-10, 10), в итоге стало видно. Просто подбирай значения теперь и всё будет супер.

В итоге получится:

```
import turtle, random

apple = turtle.Turtle()
apple.shape('circle')
apple.color('red')
apple.penup()
apple.speed(0)

xapple = 0
yapple = 0

def randomAppleXcor():
    global xapple
    xapple = random.randint(-10, 10)

def randomAppleYcor():
    global yapple
    yapple = random.randint(-10,10)


randomAppleXcor()
randomAppleYcor()

apple.goto(xapple, yapple)
```

P.s. извиняюсь за такое большое количество правок, просто каждый раз нахожу всё новое и новое

Comment: Не нужно использовать global.

Answer (score 2):

Использовать global очень плохой совет. Если хочется для создания координат использовать отдельные функции, то лучше делать так:

```
def randomAppleXcor():
    return random.randrange(-600, 600)

def randomAppleYcor():
    return random.randrange(-500,500)


xapple = randomAppleXcor()
yapple = randomAppleYcor()
```

Обе функции возвращают случайное значение, которые присваиваются переменным.